# How to get partitioning information of a table using SQLServerDatabaseMetaData API ?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I don't see relevant methods are available in that class.

P.S: This class is available in the jdbc jar provided by MS. (mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar)

Comment: You need to run your own SQL statements. SQLServerDatabaseMetaData simply implements the [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) interface as specified in the JDBC specs

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java), `SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java` (currently) makes no mention of partition information. To retrieve that information you will need to run a query against the [sys.partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql) catalog view (or similar).